# on Wall Street vs on the Wall Street

Tags: articles

Why is the article before "Wall Street" extraneous?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the name of the street is "Wall Street" not "The Wall Street." I've seen the sign, trust me. :)

Seriously, though, the only time you would use the definite article before a street name would be to distinguish it from other streets of the same name. If there were a Wall Street in Podunk, Iowa, and you were wondering if I was talking about that street when I mentioned Wall Street in a conversation, I might say, "No, I mean *the* Wall Street." You would understand that I meant the famous Wall Street in Manhattan as opposed to the (obviously inferior) Podunk version.

Comment: I take it you are thinking of Wall Street Road in Portage, Wisconsin 53901. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this may be a more subtle question than it appears: why do proper nouns not take an article in English when they do in other languages? In French, for example, you would say "*The Captain Smith drove down to the Wall Street*."
If that's what is meant, it should probably be in another forum: all I can suggest would be that it is to distinguish "Captain Smith" from "the captain of the *Smith*", or "Wall Street" from the wall street in Medievaltown (which runs below the old city wall, but is named 'Bailey Street').